# symfony parent template controller

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

Is there a standard/preferred way in Symfony to pass common variables to the base template?
There are things that are on every page, like a username in the menu that I obviously don't want to have to remember to add for every controller.

My thought was to create a controller for the template and return the data. But wondering if there is something more built in to handle this.

```
        return $this->render(
                        '@secured/account/profile.html.twig',
                        array('userForm' => $form->createView(),
                        'base' => call_base_layout_controller()
        );
```

```
{# templates/account/profile.html.twig #}
{% extends '@secured/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You could use [globals](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

Comment: Another approach is to use [embedded controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers).

Comment: Thanks, doing some research, globals and embedded controllers will work, but don't seem like the best option when building a complex site. So far I've stuck with creating a controller to hold everything that's not globally available.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find it in the current version docs but, as far as I know you can still access a lot directly from twig through the `app` twig variable defined automatically by the framework for every request https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/app_variable.html

For example, you can get the current user's username as follows:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

`app` holds `user`, `request`, `session`, `environment`, and `debug` so you can put other values needed into the session or environment variables, and fetch/render those values directly in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you want is related to the authenticated user, I would recommend what Arleigh Hix said

Otherwise you can create a class that extends `AbstractExtension` and fill it with your logic
**Anything on this class can be accessed from all your twig pages**

```
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('myGlobalData', [$this, 'myGlobalData']),
        ];
    }

    public function myGlobalData()
    {
        return "what ever you want ( ex: a query resualt..)";
    }
}
```

Than on your twig template just call it like this

```
{{ myGlobalData() }}
```

Even if it retuns an array, u can access it.